# two spanning figures in one page

Tags: floats, acm

I am using acm template and have two figures that need to span both columns. I put them like the following:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics{fig1} % size is 6.4cm x 4cm
        \subcaption{title1}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~~~~
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics{fig2}
        \subcaption{title2}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~~~~
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics{fig3}
        \subcaption{title3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{caption of this figure}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics{fig4}
        \subcaption{title4}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~~~~
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics{fig5}
        \subcaption{title5}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~~~~
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics{fig6}
        \subcaption{title6}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{caption of this figure}
\end{figure*}
```

But even though there is enough space in one page for both these figures, it puts them in two different pages. How can I put them in one signle page?

Comment: probably they are not allowed due to `dbltopfraction` but anyway you can put them both in the same `figure*` (with two `\caption`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always provide a complete test document however if you delete

```
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}
```

from the middle of your example, leaving a blank line, the entire construction will always float as a unit. (But be captioned as two figures).